# JQTouch remote page - getting back to the app

Tags: iphone, cordova, jqtouch

I've built a simple iphone app with JQTouch and PhoneGap.

From the main menu a link goes to a search form. The search form is actually 
on a web server but styled so to the user it looks like they are still in
the app but really the page has come from a Apache/php server.

The search form allows you to do search and see the results which is
great. However now you are actually using the server page how do get back to the
app menu you came from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your going to have to use something like the [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser) plugin to show your search results.  Then you can close the ChildBrowser easily and return to your app.

Comment: Here's an example that uses ChildBrowser http://www.wisejive.com/2010/11/phonegap-jquery-mobile-twitter-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening Mobile Safari or do you have a browser embedded in your app?  I'm going to assume the latter.  If so, you could nest your browser UIView inside of a UINavigationController.  That way you can have a back button at the top of the screen in the navigation bar and it can take you back to your app menu.  See the docs for UINavigationController for more details.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the reply but I'm using JQTouch to build pages and not InterfaceBuilder so there are np .xib files.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I'm not familiar with JQTouch, but FWIW, I didn't reference any .xib files and you don't need IB to create UIView, UINavigationController, etc. :)